# Не работает мобильная версия сайта

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

Начал делать адаптивную версию лендинга и зашёл на него со смартфона, чтобы посмотреть как он отображается.Но мои медиа запросы почему-то не срабатывают. С телефона сайт выглядит точно также как и с пк.
http://sy151yau.beget.tech/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать мета-тег:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
```

> значение `device-width` означает ширину экрана в пикселях CSS в масштабе 100%

- [об использовании viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: Спасибо!Помогло.

Comment: если помогло отметьте ответ как решение, если не трудно